# Error when importing sklearn.model_selection in scikit-learn 1.2

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using `scikit-learn 1.2` and when I try to import `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection` it gives me an error:

Code:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Error:

```py
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py:23
     20 from ._split import train_test_split
     21 from ._split import check_cv
---> 23 from ._validation import cross_val_score
     24 from ._validation import cross_val_predict
     25 from ._validation import cross_validate

File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:32
     30 from ..utils.fixes import delayed
     31 from ..utils.metaestimators import _safe_split
---> 32 from ..metrics import check_scoring
     33 from ..metrics._scorer import _check_multimetric_scoring, _MultimetricScorer
     34 from ..exceptions import FitFailedWarning

File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py:41
     37 from ._classification import multilabel_confusion_matrix
     39 from ._dist_metrics import DistanceMetric
---> 41 from . import cluster
     42 from .cluster import adjusted_mutual_info_score
     43 from .cluster import adjusted_rand_score
...
     19 )

File sklearn/metrics/_pairwise_distances_reduction/_base.pyx:1, in init sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._base()

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' has no attribute 'DistanceMetric32'
```

Comment: Similar question but raised from `imblearn`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74736220/importing-smote-raise-attributeerror-module-sklearn-metrics-dist-metrics-has

Comment: Check your scikit-learn version because it works fine for the latest version.