# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' has no attribute 'DistanceMetric32'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm new to scikit-learn, and currently I just want to use its train_test_split function.  Below is what I typed:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

And this is the error message:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

File ~/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py:23
     20 from ._split import train_test_split
     21 from ._split import check_cv
---> 23 from ._validation import cross_val_score
     24 from ._validation import cross_val_predict
     25 from ._validation import cross_validate

File ~/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:32
     30 from ..utils.fixes import delayed
     31 from ..utils.metaestimators import _safe_split
---> 32 from ..metrics import check_scoring
     33 from ..metrics._scorer import _check_multimetric_scoring, _MultimetricScorer
     34 from ..exceptions import FitFailedWarning

File ~/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py:41
     37 from ._classification import multilabel_confusion_matrix
     39 from ._dist_metrics import DistanceMetric
---> 41 from . import cluster
     42 from .cluster import adjusted_mutual_info_score
     43 from .cluster import adjusted_rand_score
...
     19 )

File sklearn/metrics/_pairwise_distances_reduction/_base.pyx:1, in init sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._base()

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' has no attribute 'DistanceMetric32'
```

I've tried to search for similar errors, and most of them are version issues.  My Python is 3.10.8 and scikit-learn is 1.2.0.  I tried to upgrading (1.2.0 is already the latest) and downgrading, but the error remains.  In addition, the other errors I found are lack of some other attributes rather than 'DistanceMetric32'.  Could anyone provides some ideas?

Comment: I created a conda env with python 3.10.8 and scikit-learn 1.2.0 and it works fine for me. Do you also have trouble importing other modules?

Comment: Same thing was posted a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74997030/error-when-importing-sklearn-model-selection-in-scikit-learn-1-2

Comment: (1) Can you check whether you have a 32-bit copy of Python installed? (e.g. [using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit)). (2) Are you on Windows/macOS/Linux?

Comment: Hi @hash_ir I currently have no trouble importing other modules.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderL.Hayes, thanks for the reply.  
(1) That looks like a good point!  My current python is 64 bit.  I didn't see a 32-bit Python installed in this env.
(2) I'm on Linux.