# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EuclideanDistance' on <module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' from 'C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Sorry I'm still a beginner. I want to find out if this model works properly or not, but there is an error.

```
knn_model = pickle.load(open('knn_pickle.sav', 'rb'))
   
value_Output = ''

data = (2, 12, 96, 53, 1, 1)

result_Prediction = knn_model.predict([data])
    
if(result_Prediction[0] == 1):
    value_Output = 'It works'
else:
    value_Output = "It doesn't work"
```

And then I hit this error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EuclideanDistance' on <module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' 
  from 'C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\metrics\\_dist_metrics.cp311-win_amd64.pyd'>
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: What is your scikit-learn version? You can find it via: `import sklearn` `print(sklearn.__version__)`

Comment: my scikit-learn version is 1.3.0

Comment: Your scikit-learn package seems updated. This issue seems similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74736220/.

Comment: Please habitually include essential `import`s.

Answer (score 4):

Scikit-Learn 1.2.2's `sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics` module has `EuclideanDistance()` and `EuclideanDistance32()`. However, version 1.3.0 has `EuclideanDistance32()` and `EuclideanDistance64()`, instead of `EuclideanDistance()`. I guess they replaced `EuclideanDistance()` with `EuclideanDistance64()` in 1.3.0.